# Ghidra + IDA cant detect a string but Radare2 can

Tags: ida, radare2, ghidra

Im new to reverse engineering, and ive trying Ghidra, IDA (Freeware) and Radare2 with a simple CrackMe, the problem is, both Ghidra and IDA couldnt detect a string while Radare2 (Using Cutter GUI) could figure out the name.
I used default analysis for all 3.
Is there something im missing ? because even the 'strings' command can actually find the string im looking for.

Ghidra:

[image]

IDA:

[image]

Radare2 (Cutter):

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I don't know the exact length of string. But, few things to note here are as follows:

1. Ghidra and IDA has a minimum bound on size of string to recover correct type (ghidra has a limit - or lower bound of 5).
2. This is necessary to avoid any false positives or conflicting types. And recover correct types without marking a pointer as a string. Check out this figure for your reference. Generated using Ghidra automated analysis.

[image]

In Ghidra you can change this limit (minimum is 4) in analysis section.

[image]

3. `Strings` command outputs printable characters with minimum size 4 (plus it doesn't use sophisticated type recovery algorithms like ghidra or Ida). I believe that you have a string with length less than 5 and my guess is that it must be 4 to be precise.
4. strings are usually defined in `.rodata` section. If you doubleclick on DAT_xxxx, it will take you to the location where that string is defined. There, you will see consecutive bytes bunched together by Ghidra or IDA (as shown in image-1). But, the type is not resolved as a "string".
5. In Ghidra a quick way to fix this by changing data type of DAT_xxxx label:
   Right click -> Data -> Choose Data Type -> choose string

[image]

Rereferences:

- See my question here - https://github.com/NationalSecurityAgency/ghidra/issues/2274
- strings manual - https://linux.die.net/man/1/strings
- ida pro - [How can I make IDA see a string reference?](https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/2226/how-can-i-make-ida-see-a-string-reference)

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to write such a detailed answer, i changed the data type to string and it worked perfectly and i now also understand how the minimum string's length can effect the analysis, Thank you again!